# codeigniter -- helper and nice_date

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a weird problem with CI and can't seem to figure it out.

I use data helper and nice date to compare two dates:

```
nice_date($miesiac, 'Y-m')==nice_date($obch2['data_zgloszenia'], 'Y-m')
```

Ąnd this is generraly works, but, i have first time problem:
[image: error]

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Backup\system\helpers\date_helper.php on line 553
> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Error

Message: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Filename: helpers/date_helper.php

Line Number: 553

Backtrace:

This goes at end of array, who has about 1500 rows.

Thank you for your help and suggestions .

Comment: there is no question in your question